# How to decide if a fragment's color is white or not?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, glsl, webgl, three.js

I have many circles next to each other in my scene (white circles and circles with different colors). I would like to blur the white circles only. (White means (1,1,1) in my case.)

My question is: how should I select and blur the white fragments only with my fragment shader?

I want to do something like this in GLSL:

```
if (my_current_fragment's_color == white)
{blur current fragment;}
else
{do not blur current fragment}
```

(I have a working blur effect, but it's bluring the whole scene unappropriately because I cannot make a decision in my code based on my fragments' color.)

How should I do this? What is the exact match of the above code in GLSL language? 
How can I decide if a fragment's color is white? Do you guys have any idea?

---

If you may need, here is my code:

```
    vertexShader: [
        //"#define KERNEL_SIZE 25.0",
        "uniform vec2 uImageIncrement;",
        "varying vec2 vUv;",
        "void main() {",
        "vUv = uv - ( ( KERNEL_SIZE - 1.0 ) / 2.0 ) * uImageIncrement;",
        "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
        "}"
    ].join("\n"),
    fragmentShader: [
        //"#define KERNEL_SIZE 25",
        "uniform float cKernel[ KERNEL_SIZE ];",
        "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
        "uniform vec2 uImageIncrement;",
        "varying vec2 vUv;",
        "void main() {",
            "vec2 imageCoord = vUv;",
            "vec4 sum = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );",
            "for( int i = 0; i < KERNEL_SIZE; i ++ ) {",


            "sum += texture2D( tDiffuse, imageCoord ) * cKernel[ i ];",
            //THE ABOVE LINE SHOULD BE RUN FOR WHITE FRAGMENTS ONLY. BUT HOW?


            "imageCoord += uImageIncrement;",
            "}",
            "gl_FragColor = sum;",
        "}"
```

Comment: You could lookup the current imageCoord and compare it's components to white before performing the loop, the problem is it could cause some aliasing in pixels near the border of the circles. I'll leave to someone with more experience on the subject to formalize an answer. I am also a little bit confused about how your shader is sampling the data for the blur.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is going to be really hard, and you're going to have to figure out some compromise, unless you can render the white circles to a different framebuffer to begin with.

Let's say you start with this.

[image: white circle over pink triangle with blue background]

If you only apply the blur kernel to the white pixels, you'll get this:

[image: white circle with blurred interior over pink triangle with blue background]

Since the blue pixels don't get the blur kernel, the white pixels can't bleed into the blue.  Only the pink and blue pixels can bleed into the white.

So you try to separate the image into the white parts and the non-white parts:

[image: white circle] [image: black circle over pink triangle with blue background]

And then you can blur the white parts separately, and recombine (either in multiple steps, or all in the same shader).  But you have to figure out what to recombine it with.  If you recombine it with the original image, the hard-edge white will still be there.  If you recombine it with the image with only the non-white parts, you'll get a hard black edge instead.

[image: white circle with halo over pink triangle with blue background] [image: white circle with halo and black edge over pink triangle with blue background]

### Solutions

- You can render the white circles into a separate texture to begin with, blur that, and layer it on top of everything else.
- You can scale the kernel so that the kernel blurs "outwards" (dilates), so when you blur the white circle against the black background, white pixels stay white.  This will eliminate the edges.
- You can blur an area of the image near, but not exactly equal to, the white circles.  For example, you can use the blurred white circles as an alpha mask to blend between the blurred image and the sharp image.
- You can figure out a way to make the white circles look blurry to begin with.

Comment: Yes, exactly! MFlBm.png is what I'm looking for! Could you please show me a GLSL example how to do this? How to separate the image into white parts and non-white parts, and recombine it with the original image? 
Any further help or a link also would be great and appreciated!

Comment: @Fract: If you are having problems writing the code, you can ask for help.  But this is not a "programmers for hire" forum.  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm just looking for a simple IF statement written in GLSL that decides if a fragement's color is white or not. Something like this (but of course written in GLSL): If (my_current_fragment's_color == white) {}. What is the exact match of this condition in GLSL language? This is my question.

Comment: How did you draw the images above? Could you please send me the code which draw the pictures above? This would solve my problem.

Comment: @Fract: I made those pictures in an image editor, not with GLSL.  I would separate a sample `samp` into white and non-white components by computing the distance from white `dist`, use this number to calculate an alpha value `alpha` in the range 0-1 where 0 signifies not white and 1 signifies white, then `samp * alpha` will give you the white part and `(1 - samp) * alpha` will give you the non-white part.

Comment: There **is** a way to do `if (color == white) { ... }` in GLSL, however, you don't want to do that.  You only think you want to do that.

Comment: I see. Sorry, maybe I wasn't detailed enough: my circles are moving all the time randomly on the screen. I would like to use blur effect as a post processing effect. So I have to blur my white circles frame by frame without knowing their actual coordinates on the screen. I have to search for them frame by frame based on their color. If my understanding is correct in this case I really need that "if (color == white) { . . . }" stuff. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Fract: The "distance from white" is the distance of the color, not the distance of the pixel on the screen.  I.e., black is far from white, but light gray is close to white.  Colors are vectors too, so they have distances.

Comment: I see. I learned something new. My question now: how to compute "dist" (the distance from white)? Furthermore how to use this number to calculate an alpha value? Etc. I'm a novice to GLSL. However I really want to learn these things. Could you please show me a tutorial, link or anything else that explains how to do these calculations in GLSL?

Comment: @Fract: Unfortunately, most of what I use for learning GLSL is the GLSL specification, which is a bit dense.  You can compute distance from white using `dot(vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0), color)` -- this will give you 3.0 for white and 0.0 for black.